# Distinguish between multiple SQL Server instances

Tags: windows-sbs-2003, sql-server

In Task Manager I see two instances of **sqlserver.exe**. One is consuming a significant number of resources, so I'd like to attempt to harness it in a bit.  How do I determine which database this corresponds to?

The two SQL Server DB's we have are for **Sharepoint** and **SBSMonitoring**, both of which have a **sqlserver.exe** in their respective `\Binn` directories.  I suspect that the **SBSMonitoring** is the one which is allocating resources, since **Sharepoint** rarely has any changes to it.  However, I'd like to verify this for sure, and Task Manager doesn't seem to be the tool to find that info.

This is Windows SBS 2003, with SQL 2000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be to view the PID column in Task Manager, find the PID for each instance of SQL Server, and compare that to the PID in the current SQL Server log for each instance.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. And for the record, I was correct that the **SBSMonitoring** instance is the larger.

Comment: Glad to help...